# Has a Markov chain in compact metric space a stationary distribution (possibly non-unique)?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $Y_n$ be a Markov chain in a compact metric space. Is it true that it has a stationary distribution?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the Markov chain, corresponding to the regular or non-absorbing restrictions for Markov chains on finite sets? Can you share any other context for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One criteria for deciding if a Markov chain (or process), defined on a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) has a stationary distribution, is the [Krylov-Bogoljubov  theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov%E2%80%93Bogolyubov_theorem).

For a better treatment of the subject than the one given by the wikipedia link, you can look at [this document](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Convergence.pdf), especially at section 1.4 for the theorem, and previous sections for the corresponding definitions.

The tl;dr version is, if the Markov chain verifies a type of "continuity" (the Feller property) and is "concentrated on a compact set" (ie, the distributions $P^k(\cdot, x_0)$ are [tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures)), then you can guarantee existence of a stationary distribution.

So, the answer to your question is, not necesarily.

First, to apply these results, you also need your space to be complete and to be separable. In which case the space is Polish and compact, so you verify the tightness condition. I have not seen any reference in which the convergence of Markov chains in spaces that are not Polish is studied.

But even in this case, you need the Markov chain to verify the Feller property to conclude existence.

Comment: compact metric space implies closed i.e. complete and compact implies separable too. So, compact implies Polish.

Comment: d'oh. Of course, you are correct. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: is this a tight sequence? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225721/tight-sequence-of-operator

Comment: nice answer and nice links

Comment: you are welcome